# Client send cert but GetClientCertificate always receives as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, x509certificate, client-certificates

Web api always receive `GetClientCertificate` as null. Its using with IISExpress and no need to host certificate on IISExpress or IIS. Certificate exists on certificate Store on server. Just want to validate manually like, client send cert file and web api code validate cert manually by looking into cert store on server (no iis validation).

went through couple of post on same issue but it needs to host cert on IIS/IISExpress.

Tried:
client send the certificate as below, And expected to receive on server side.
client send certificate:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                var certifcates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "07a49ef049795a07be786512359be34d234e4548", false);
                var cert = certifcates[0];
                handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
                var client = new HttpClient(handler);
                var s ="xml content to post";
                var data = new StringContent(s, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
                var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:51567/api/PostContent", data).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

web api expecting to receive client cert on `GetClientCertificate` as below but, its always getting null.
web api:

```
var cert = httpActionContext.Request.GetClientCertificate();
                if (cert == null)
            ...
            else
            ..
```

Comment: Try changing the URL from HTTP to HTTPS.  If still fail use sniffer to check version of TLS being used.  The default may be TLS 1.0/1.1 which will fail.  You may need to specify in code TLS 1.2/1.3.

Comment: have tried on `https` endpoint and by setting `var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls
};` still GetClientCert is null.

Comment: check if you search for right store. Shouldn't it be CurrentUser store? If indeed LocalMachine is used, make sure if your app has permissions to access the key. And check if certificate has associated private key at all.

Comment: Its pointing to same SSL though its not receiving on web api.  (Verified by opening SSL URL on browser and see cert thumbprint match to client sent cert).  But, GetClientCert on api remains null.